# Check for Installed Softwares on Remote machine in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a bunch of TeamCity agents (Windows, Linux, AWS, OpenShift). To have consistent state it is desirable that all of them have the same software+version installed. Manually checking them is very tedious

Hence I have decided to have an application which shows this information as a dashboard, i.e. a snapshot view of all the agents and the software installed on them. I have decided to use Python(v3.6) for the implementation. I am not a hardcore developer hence this will be learn and do project for me.

I was thinking of some sort of a code-base on all agents that would fetch the necessary details for that agent only.

I will then have a central server that will utilize this data from each agent and then display it in the form of a dashboard.

Please let me know if the above design is the proper way of doing it or please suggest some alternate if any.

If I can have some pointers as how to go about implementing it that would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control over the agents' machines, consider using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to enforce the desired configurations. In general it is much more convenient an safe to control agents' configurations rather than ask them if they have proper ones. And with Ansible or similar configuration management tool you can do this in a scalable way.